# How to hash a word using Hashing technique in python using list / dictionary(as c++ )?

Tags: python-3.x, list, dictionary, c++11, hash

I want to hash a word in python to count each letter occurence.

**c++ code:**

```
     int *arr = new int[256]();
    for(int i=0;i<s.size();i++){
         arr[s[i]]++;
        }
```

I want to implement the same in python using dictionary or list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By using Dictionaries

```
hsh={}
for i in s:
    if i in hsh:
        hsh[i]+=1
    else:
        hsh[i]=1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
s=[3,4,5,4,5]
dict1={}
for i in range(len(s)):
    if(s[i] in dict1.keys()):
        dict1[s[i]]=dict1[s[i]]+1
    else:
         dict1[s[i]]=0
print(dict1)
```

output

```
{3: 0, 4: 1, 5: 1}
```

Hope this will answer your question

Comment: it is giving an error in `dict[s[i]]+=1` as **key error** , it is stating that the key is not found

Comment: do you want to increment s elements by 1?

Comment: No, i want to store the occurence of each letter

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `Counter`, after first splitting the string into a list:

```
from collections import Counter

s = 'hello world'
c = Counter(list(s))
print(c)
```

Output

```
Counter({'l': 3, 'o': 2, 'h': 1, ' ': 1, 'd': 1, 'r': 1, 'w': 1, 'e': 1})
```